# Unable to make client server Bluetooth serial connection between Android phone and PC

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

According to my research it is most probably due to wrong UUID or because my PC doesn't support SPP.

My SG4 is used as a Server while PC is used as a client.
When I use standard serial UUID my android code never executes after `.connect()`.

I thought I have fixed it by doing: `mmDevice.getUuids()` and then by using one of those UUIDs. And yes, it has executed the further code then. However, later I found out that it didn't set up serial connection but some different one.

CODE:

```
 // ParcelUuid[] list = mmDevice.getUuids();
 // UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(list[0].toString());
 UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
 mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
 mmSocket.connect();
 mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
```

That array `list` has contained these UUIDs:

```
00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
0000111b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Does that mean that my PC doesn't support serial connection or what? I am using windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SPP profile that supports serial connection is not related with your Operative System but with the Bluetooth module installed in your PC.

Knowing that your system is Windows 8, I guess your PC is relative new so surely comes with the new Bluetooth modules that doesn't support SPP.

You can still use an external Bluetooth USB dongle that comes with SPP profile like the asus bluetooth bt 211.

Comment: Wow, I think you are right... and I have spent like 10 hours trying to figure out what is wrong... Do you know if my mouse dongle could work as Bluetooth USB dongle you referred me to? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I hardly think that. Mouse drivers are not expected to create a COM port in your computer, so even if it supports that profile you won't see the data come out.

I recently was thinking how do they in the new Bluetooth to send serial data without SPP. I guess some of the new profiles should support that communication.

Maybe this helps: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/71/is-there-a-serial-port-profile-for-ble/

Answer (score 1):

PCs and Android devices do not usually advertise an SPP service profile until it has been properly established previously, either with a paired remote device, or with a local application. This makes sense, because the PC or Android has no idea what to do when an unknown stream of data starts coming in wirelessly.

After a PC pairs with a SPP device, is typically assigns a virtual COM port. Sometimes, the SPP service is not enabled, until the COM port has been opened.

An Android device needs an App to open an SPP service, and register the listener.